# Maseches Kilayim with pictures

Tags: mishna, maseches-kilayim

Are there any commentaries or guides to Maseches Kilayim that include pictures of the plants under discussion? Artscroll has footnotes about what each plant could be, but it is too much work to Google all of them.

The same goes for other masechtos in Zeraim that are heavy on names of specific plants.

Comment: Felix is the classic. It's out of print though

Comment: Yes, he wrote extensively on plant life in Tanach and Shas and included illustrations and pictures.  For a listing of his publications see here: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/יהודה_פליקס#פרסומים

If you have access to a good library you should be able to find his sefarim.  This link might help you locate which libraries have his books: http://worldcat.org/identities/lccn-n83237087/